# Is dup(file_des) equivalent to fcntl(filedes, F_DUPFD, 0)?

Tags: c, linux

Is `dup(file_des)` equivalent to `fcntl(filedes, F_DUPFD, 0)`? If `yes`, then which is better to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it exactly the same. According to the [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) standard

> The dup() function provides an alternative interface to the service
>   provided by fcntl() using the F_DUPFD command. The call dup(fildes)
>   shall be equivalent to:
>
> fcntl(fildes, F_DUPFD, 0);

`dup()` is shorter and easier to read, I would use that.